# Magento upgrade from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am upgrading magento version 1.5 store to magento version 1.7. Current store has more than 1000 products, more than 100 categories, more than 20 attribute sets, more than 500 customers,more than 500 orders and Database size is more than 600MB.

Above details are mentioned in order to have the idea of store size. Furthermore, I am trying it **on local machine with wamp server** installed.

Here are the steps involved to upgrade:

1. Export Current Database (Imported it in gzipped format with option "Disable foreign key checks" checked). As I was unable to export it in normal sql formate due to large size of database.
2. Created new database and imported the Database exported.
3. Downloaded fresh 1.7 stable version from magentocommerce.com
4. Tried to install this fresh magento 1.7 in newly created Database, in which exported database was recently imported.

Next steps were to install theme, copy extensions and copy media folders.

But when I tried to install magento 1.7, it always give me this error :

**"This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at `http://localhost/magento17/index.php/install/` has resulted in too many redirects. "**

Here is the link to which I was following:

[Link I followed](http://way2discuss.blogspot.com/2012/07/magento-upgrade-15-to-17-and-16-to-17.html)

Note that my main focus is upgrading from 1.5 to 1.7, so much focus must be on that rather then resolving this issue if it is not the right way to do.

And If there is any better and proven way to upgrade to 1.7 from 1.5, kindly share it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upgrade you dont need to install and move DB and theme.

Refer this link.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento

Note: If you followed best practices in Magento and didn't modify core code then upgrade should run smoothly.
Expected issues are that your Local and Community folder modules might need some fixes.

Comment: Is there anyway I can check on it, if there is any core file modified?

Comment: create a test site and run upgrade if it fails.

Comment: Other way is to compare core files using some tool.